# using sql loader in ruby

Tags: ruby, oracle, sql-loader

I just wonder if you know where to find a tutorial or samples of a Ruby script using sql *loader?

Comment: Niklas can you clarify what you mean by "sql loader"? Are you referring to Oracle's "sqlldr"? Or something else? BTW if it's a command line utility you can just do `system("command goes here")`

Comment: Oh yeah Sorry! yes I meant using sqlldr for loading a text data into an oracle table. I want to use Ruby for doing this and not any other script language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlldr is a command line utility that uses a control file to guide it.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_concepts.htm#g1013706

An example using system and referencing the loader.ctl control file would be:

```
system("sqlldr username@server/password control=loader.ctl")
```

Comment: thx, I tried that and it works but the problem here is that I only can load the first row of my data. The data file is something like this:
text1|text2|text3
text4|text5|text6
and so on. But I can just load the first row. How can I tell sqlldr to continue after newline?
Thx in advanced!

Comment: @Niklas:  What does your sqlldr control file look like?

Comment: This is my .ctl file:
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'text.dat'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE dbas_te
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "str '|\n'"
(
   STRISDN INTEGER EXTERNAL,
   STRIMSI INTEGER EXTERNAL,
   ACCOUNT_TYPE INTEGER EXTERNAL,
   PROD_TYPE CHAR(7)
)
By the way, I have some swedish charecters in my test.dat file like ä, ö... but those chars are not visible in DB either.
Thx for you are patient with me. As I told before I'm a beginner in programming and grateful for all help I can get.

Comment: Plzzz, somebody :-(
Is it possible to change the charset in parfile? If yes, how can I change the charset to include swedish chars?

Comment: Problem solved by adding CHARACTERSET UTF8 in .ctl file. It was so easy :-)
Thx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure your configuration (sqlloader commandline switches + controlfile + datafile) works outside Ruby. Then you can call it via system() as previous answer said.